# Find the principal value of $z=\ln\left(i\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Steps that I have taken:
Substitute $\tanh(π/2)$ with $C$.
Then we have $\ln(i\cdot C)=\ln|c| +i(\arg z)$.
I am desperately stuck here. 
I also tried expressing $\tanh$ by definition using the powers of $e$, but yielding no results.

Comment: What expression did you get for $\tanh \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions

Comment: Okay, so you know that the $i$ is pretty irrelevant, and the only problem is to find $\ln \left(\tanh \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. I don't know of a nice closed form, but a series representation isn't hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z=\ln\left[i\tanh\left(\frac\pi2\right)\right]$$
$$z=\ln\left[i\left(\frac{e^{\pi/2}-e^{-\pi/2}}{e^{\pi/2}+e^{-\pi/2}}\right)\right]$$
$$z=\ln\left[i\left(\frac{e^{\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}+1}\right)\right]$$

> $$\ln(x+iy)=\ln{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)$$

[See Complex Logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)

since quantity inside $\ln$ is imaginary $\arg(z)=\pi/2$
$$z=\ln \left(\frac{e^{\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}+1}\right)+i\left(\frac\pi2\right)$$

Note: General value can be acquired by replacing principle value of $\arg=\theta$ by it's general value  $2n\pi+\theta$ .

Comment: Shouldn't y/x in our case be tanh(pi/2)/0, and hence atanh is undefined?

Comment: Oh, don't mind my last comment. It is clear from the representation in the Gaussian plane that the argument is pi/2. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Done, feel free to cooperate in the future